# Update Multiple Rows with array

Tags: laravel

I have a invoice form and want to update the data. I tried but get the below error,

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist.

But when I use `$match = Stock::where('inv_no','=',$inv_no)->first();`, it update on one row while i have two rows or more than one.

What can I do to update those data?

Controller.

```
public function update(Request $request, $inv_no)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    // dd($data);
    // for($i = 0; $i<$request->pid; $i++)
    foreach ($request->pid as $i => $dt) {
        $match = Stock::where('inv_no', '=', $inv_no)->get();
        $match->update(['pid' => $request->pid[$i],
            'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
            'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
            'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
            'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber,
            'driverName' => $request->driverName,
            'remark' => $request->remark,
        ]);
        // dd($match);

        return $this->index();
    }
}
```

My  `$request->all()`

```
array:8 [▼
    "_token" => "6YdueIejLzorveQnzEaG8Fx5eYH9Lk1qcL1LQXya"
    "supplierName" => "DAR ERICA 3"
    "receiptNumber" => "5555KK"
    "truckNumber" => "T 500 FGT"
    "driverName" => "JOHN EMMA"
    "remark" => "OK"
    "pid" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "2"
        1 => "1"
    ]
    "qty" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "100"
        1 => "100"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solution of your problem.
Updates can also be performed against any number of models that match a given query. In this example, all flights that are active and have a destination of San Diego will be marked as delayed:

```
App\Flight::where('active', 1)
          ->where('destination', 'San Diego')
          ->update(['delayed' => 1]);
```

Comment: i that means you want me to change the table?

Comment: I understand that there is two record that has same `inv_no` and you want to update with a single code. Then you should change your code `Stock::where('inv_no', '=', $inv_no)->update([...]);`

Comment: i used like that but it update two raw with the same date of `pid` one, that means if `pid=>2` and second `pid=>2` while the pid and qty are different